# Wordpress Styling destroys Angular Application Layout

Tags: angular, wordpress

I use a Wordpress website in combination with an Angular application. Unfortunately, the CSS of Wordpress destroys the application. This also affects the material components, for example. My solution so far is to break the CSS files in function.php when retrieving the permalink.

```
if(is_page('AngularApp')) {

    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

    }
```

Unfortunately, the problem here is that the header and footer say goodbye in style without wordpress CSS ;)

Is there an elegant way to make Angular applications immune to external CSS from websites?

Comment: Insert your angular app in a iframe inside the page or change all your wordpress style in order to don't have effect on your angular elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sharing the structure about your merging both frameworks can help.
So far, a couple of ideas in mind are to use a better strategy using unique decorator's names using IDs mainly, and then probably helps to use SCSS instead of CSS files.

```css
#main-angular-container {
  .contents {
    // rules
  }
}
```